# Should nbf/exp in a JWT be numeric?

Tags: jwt

Is there an official word on whether the `nbf` and `exp` claims in a JWT payload should be passed as strings, or as numbers?

On one hand, they are UNIX timestamps, technically numeric. On the other, there is some value in having the claims data structure be representable as a strongly typed associative array (along the lines of `Map<string,string>`).

Comment: _"On the other, there is some value in having the claims data structure be representable as a strongly typed associative array (along the lines of Map<string,string>)."_ Could you explain what value you see in that?

Comment: @jps: Not really, no. They speak about what goes into *parsed* tokens, I'm interested in the JSON of the claims portion.

Comment: @phuzi: the value is that you can parse the claims JSON into a `Map<string, string>` :)

Comment: The question was about parsed claims, but the accepted answer explains what is in the token.  You asked for *an official word*, and the answer quotes RFC7519, that's the official word about JWT.

Comment: The [official specification - RFC7519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519) explicitly states that nbf, along with exp and iat, MUST be numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From RFC7519: those claims are of datatype `NumericDate`.

> NumericDate:
> **A JSON numeric value** representing the number of seconds from
> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the specified UTC date/time,
> ignoring leap seconds.  This is equivalent to the IEEE Std 1003.1,
> 2013 Edition [POSIX.1] definition "Seconds Since the Epoch", in
> which each day is accounted for by exactly 86400 seconds, other
> than that non-integer values can be represented.  See RFC 3339
> [RFC3339] for details regarding date/times in general and UTC in
> particular.

So it's numeric.

Comment: That's what the accepted answer of the suggested duplicate target already says.